# AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.optimizers.experimental' has no attribute 'Adafactor'

Tags: tensorflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYHG2.png)

Dear all,

I am using Tensorflow 2.10, and cannot import Adafactor optimizer. Can anyone help me with some tips to solve this issue?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your TensorFlow version to v2.11.
I checked GitHub that its available on TF v2.11 and not available on TF 2.10 yet.

- TF v2.10:
  https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/v2.10.0/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental
- TF v2.11:
  https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/v2.11.0/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental